# FQDN works but short hostname resolution doesn't

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

What do I need to do so that foobar resolution works in the same way as foobar.domain.com resolution on all clients? Basically my FQDN resolution works but short hostname resolution doesn't.

I am using BIND9.4.2 on OpenSuse 11.3 and this is an internal environment.

I am aware that there is similar thread but it deals with Windows environment and WINS and other things and so I didn't post there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How should your clients be aware of the fqdn you want them to use if you don't tell them first?

On most Unix computer this is done by filling the correct option in /etc/resolv.conf.
Have a look at [resolv.conf(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf), especially the domain and search options (*beware, they are mutually exclusive*).

If your client get their IP configuration throught DHCP, the option could be set this way to.
But this depend of which dhcp server **and** client you use.

Comment: okies I will do that! Thanks for the quick answer Benoit! But now I guess I have a deeper problem. Actually we are configuring this DNS server for a special area in the college. Now if anyone who is inside the special area tries to access foobar, how can I have it (DNS Server/DHCP Server/Workstation -- I don't know which) configure to search for first foobar.special-area.com and then foobar.college.com without having the person enter it so himself ?

Comment: If your clients get their IP throught DHCP you have two options:

 1. Configure your DHCP to give several fqdn to these specific client
 2. Configure these client to supersede the fqdn sent by the dhcp server with the extra fqdn

If your client are configured by hand, simply add the following line to their /etc/resolv.conf:

    search foobar.special-area.com foobar.exemple.com

Also, remove or comment any line starting by "*domain*" in the file.